# External links not opening in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, taskbar, url, hyperlink

I'm running in Windows 10 Pro. Chrome is my default browser.

When I click on the Chrome icon in my taskbar to open it, and then click on any external URL link, for example a link in a Microsoft Teams message, nothing happens. Chrome doesn't open the link.

If I close the browser and then click on the link, it opens a new instance of Chrome and the link comes up, and clicking other links work.

But if I close Chrome and click on the Chrome icon in my taskbar again, it gets back into the bad state where external URL links do not work.

Comment: do you have sharex installed?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was as follows. In the shortcut to Chrome in the Taskbar, I had gone to Properties > Advanced, and checked the "Run As Administrator" box. That was causing the issue. When I unchecked the box, I had no other issues opening external links in Chrome.